# Talend Open Studio tRestClient errors out when trying to POST

Tags: talend

I'm trying to POST a basic row to a REST API using tRestClient and I keep getting an error HTTP 400 Bad Request. I tried GET to get data back from the REST API and it works fine, just doing POST/PUT fails. I believe that it might be how the body of the POST is being constructed. I'm trying to POST JSON object. I also tried Using tWriteJSONField to construct the JSON for POST and I still get the same message. Does Anyone know a proper way How to POST JSON object via Talend to a REST API? Their documentation hasn't been very helpful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide a JSON object, you should use the component **tRest** and activate **POST** mode. A new box **HTTP Body** opens up. Here you can enter the JSON like so:

```
"{
    \"MyJSONParam\":\"category_a\",
    \"MyJSONValue\":\"5678\"
}"
```

If you want to use **tRestClient**, you simply have to put the parameters in the box **Query parameters:** and add everything you want.